# Parsing and displaying nested JSON in Django Template

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to print the results of an API call which is returning JSON results nested relatively deeply. I am doing this project with Python 2.7 and Django 1.11.

I have the following view.py function:

```
def nlu_analysis(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    text2send = request.POST.get('text2send')
    natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
        version='2017-02-27',
        username='####',
        password='####')

    response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
        text=text2send,
        features=[features.Entities(), ..., features.SemanticRoles()])

  return render(request, 'watson_nlu/analysis.html', {'data': response})
```

When I use the following template code in my .html file:

```
{% for k in data.keywords %}
    <p>Text - {{ k.text }}</p>
    <p>Relevance - {{ k.relevance }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

to parse and display JSON with one level of nesting like this:

```
 'keywords': [{
    'relevance': 0.946673,
    'text': 'eyes'
}]
```

Everything is great and it displays 'eyes' and 0.946673 as expected.

I can't figure out the appropriate syntax for getting to the 'anger', 'joy', etc. results that are nested more deeply such as this:

```
{
'emotion': {
    'document': {
        'emotion': {
            'anger': 0.195192,
            'joy': 0.082313,
            'sadness': 0.644314,
            'fear': 0.207166,
            'disgust': 0.103676
        }
    }
}
```

What is the most efficient method for accomplishing this objective?

It is definitely NOT:

```
<p>Anger - {{ data['emotion.document.template.anger'] }}</p>
```

Advance newbie gratitude and good juju for your help.

Comment: @RajaSimon I tried, <p>Anger - {{ data.emotion.document.template.anger }}</p> and it returned nothing but 'Anger - '. Any other thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. It returns, Anger - {u'document': {u'emotion': {u'anger': 0.088841, u'joy': 0.048228, u'sadness': 0.115575, u'fear': 0.078872, u'disgust': 0.33166}}}

Comment: @RajaSimon, oops! I my typo. I built up the call layer by layer after your suggestion and realized I included the typo 'template' instead of 'emotion' in the third layer. Works now. If you want to enter your assistance as a solution rather than a comment I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the dict of dict with `.` so the solution to your question is `data.emotion.document.emotion.anger`

Comment: With the JSON structured as it is in the original post the precise syntax would be `data.emotion.document.emotion.anger` but the solution absolutely solved the problem. Thanks.